# Stack Overflow, Redis, and Cache invalidation

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis

Now that Stack Overflow uses redis, do they handle cache invalidation the same way?  i.e. a list of identities hashed to a query string + name (I guess the name is some kind of purpose or object type name).

Perhaps they then retrieve individual items that are missing from the cache directly by id (which bypasses a bunch of database indexes and uses the more efficient clustered index instead perhaps).  That'd be smart (the rehydration that Jeff mentions?).

Right now, I'm struggling to find a way to pivot all of this in a succinct way.  Are there any examples of this kind of thing that I could use to help clarify my thinking prior to doing a first cut myself?

Also, I'm wondering where the cutoff is between using a .net cache (System.Runtime.Caching or System.Web.Caching) and going out and using redis.  Or is Redis just hands down faster?

Here's the original SO question from 2009:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-does-stackoverflow-handle-cache-invalidation

A couple of other links:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stackoverflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how/69172#69172

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110320/stack-overflow-db-performance-and-redis-cache

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I honestly can't decide if this is a SO question or a MSO question, but:

Going off to another system is *never* faster than querying local memory (as long as it is keyed); simple answer: we use both! So we use:

- local memory
- else check redis, and update local memory
- else fetch from source, and update redis and local memory

This then, as you say, causes an issue of cache invalidation - although actually that isn't *critical* in most places. But for this - redis events (pub/sub) allow an easy way to broadcast keys that are changing to all nodes, so they can drop their local copy - meaning: next time it is needed we'll pick up the new copy from redis. Hence we broadcast the key-names that are changing against a single event channel name.

Tools: redis on ubuntu server; BookSleeve as a redis wrapper; protobuf-net and GZipStream (enabled / disabled automatically depending on size) for packaging data.

So: the redis pub/sub events are used to invalidate the cache for a given key from **one** node (the one that knows the state has changed) immediately (pretty much) to **all** nodes.

Regarding distinct processes (from comments, "do you use any kind of shared memory model for multiple distinct processes feeding off the same data?"): no, we don't do that. Each web-tier box is only really hosting one process (of any given tier), with multi-tenancy *within* that, so inside the same process we might have 70 sites. For legacy reasons (i.e. "it works and doesn't need fixing") we primarily use the http cache with the site-identity as part of the key.

For the few massively data-intensive parts of the system, we have mechanisms to persist to disk so that the in-memory model can be passed between successive app-domains as the web naturally recycles (or is re-deployed), but that is unrelated to redis.

Here's a related example that shows the **broad flavour only** of how this might work - spin up a number of instances of the following, and then type some key names in:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string channelInvalidate = "cache/invalidate";
        using(var pub = new RedisConnection("127.0.0.1"))
        using(var sub = new RedisSubscriberConnection("127.0.0.1"))
        {
            pub.Open();
            sub.Open();

            sub.Subscribe(channelInvalidate, (channel, data) =>
            {
                string key = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Invalidated {0}", key);
            });
            Console.WriteLine(
                    "Enter a key to invalidate, or an empty line to exit");
            string line;
            do
            {
                line = Console.ReadLine();
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    pub.Publish(channelInvalidate, line);
                }
            } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));
        }
    }
}
```

What you should see is that when you type a key-name, it is shown immediately in all the running instances, which would then dump their local copy of that key. Obviously in real use the two connections would need to be put somewhere and kept open, so would **not** be in `using` statements. We use an almost-a-singleton for this.

Comment: does the event also comes back and invalidate the in-memory version as well?  If so, cool.  re: in-memory -- do you use any kind of shared memory model for multiple distinct processes feeding off the same data?  I'm seeing a potential for duplication of the in-memory component.

Comment: thanks Marc.  Now digesting information (mental cogs haven't finished turning yet).  Managing the in-memory expiration from outside is a *very* nice touch.  Hadn't thought of that.  (!)

Comment: @sgtz I don't know; the redis choice was before I started

Comment: ty.  Now have something hacked together.  How important is Cache optimisation in the SO world?  Hopefully my version 2 will be more IoC-ish.  I want to adapt it to something else already.

Comment: @sgtz we cache like a crazy thing, so cache performance is very important. Invalidation is less critical, to be honest. We're pretty happy with our current setup.

Comment: Mark, since the user profile and other details pertaining to a user is cached in redis, how do you remove them from the cache when the user close the browser ?Does Booksleeve supports a sliding expiry when we add items to the cache ? I just started using Booksleeve with my Asp.Net MVC app and would like do this, i am storing userid as the Key. Thanks !

Comment: this is a helpful way to quickly configure cache invalidation with redis http://www.nuget.org/packages/redismemorycacheinvalidation

Comment: what is `RedisConnection and RedisSubscriberConnection` class ? which assembly i need to add to get access of the classes called `RedisConnection and RedisSubscriberConnection`  ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar those are in StackExchange.Redis, available on NuGet

Comment: @MarcGravell i am interested to understand the code you have given here. what the above code is doing?  what RedisConnection class does ? and what RedisSubscriberConnection class does ?

Comment: @MarcGravell i really want to understand your code what those lines are doing. there is one pub and one sub. would you explain your code. thanks

Comment: @MonojitSarkar in redis, subscription connections are very different to regular command connections; "publish" goes over the regular command connection; "subscribe" goes over the other. So... that's really all there is to it...

Comment: @MarkGravell , the fact that the command part of the system knows about the cache key format used by the query part of the system isn't introducing coupling between them ?