# Why is refreshing stackoverflow.com while bypassing the browser cache invariably faster than a regular refresh?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, browser-cache

I intentionally didn't put it on meta, because I'm asking the question out of interest in the technical topic of how any webpage could ever be faster without a cache than with.  This has been my consistent experience ever since I've started using Stack. It's quite frustrating, actually.

It's also peculiar and fascinating.

The right answer gets a pony!

Comment: your computer is slow? you have small amount of free RAM and slow disk?

Comment: use the chrome builtin profiler to find out...

Comment: @HubertKario oooh, that is probably it.  you're a clever one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackoverflow, Redis, and Cache invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596877/stackoverflow-redis-and-cache-invalidation)